# Python Handling differenct date formats in a columns including null

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a csv with a date column so after fetching it using pandas. I am trying to insert into mysql db.
My requirement is that it should look for null values and make them 'None' and then irrespective of date format it should convert it to 2019-07-02 this format. below is my code

```py
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\adminuser\Desktop\CSAExcel\test.csv', parse_dates =  True , usecols = ['number','active','short_description','incident_state','caller_id','assignment_group','assigned_to','sys_created_on','sys_created_by','opened_at','opened_by','closed_at','closed_by','resolved_at','u_reported_by','u_reported_by.country','u_type'],encoding='cp1252')
df2 = df1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) 
df2['created_on']= df2['created_on'].apply(lambda t: None if pd.isnull(t) else datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I am getting error an integer is required (got type str)

[image: Please have a look at column highlighted in below picture]

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here. My guess is you spend some time googling solutions and you have different approaches weaved into one. I'll attempt to give you an easy to understand approach, but for common problems like parsing dates, various methods exist. In your snippet, there are two clear problems.

1. First you replace the NaN values for empty strings, but then in the lambda function you condition on a null value, so this is redundant. So we can remove the second line.
   Asides, why do you want None instead of np.nan?
2. The lambda function assumes a timestamp, which is a POSIX timestamp, similar to what is returned by time.time(). The column 'created_on' does not contain that, but a string.

My approach will do the following. It uses [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), which does the heavy lifting here. It will convert the str value to a datetime object. (actually, it takes various datatypes, including strings or Series of strings). If you pass a NaN value in to_datetime(), it will return a NaT value. So then we replace those to None.

Can you try if the following works?

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\adminuser\Desktop\CSAExcel\test.csv', usecols = ['number','active','short_description','incident_state','caller_id','assignment_group','assigned_to','sys_created_on','sys_created_by','opened_at','opened_by','closed_at','closed_by','resolved_at','u_reported_by','u_reported_by.country','u_type'],encoding='cp1252')
df1['created_on']= pd.to_datetime(df1['created_on'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df1['created_on'] = df1['created_on'].apply(lambda t: None if pd.isnull(t) else t)
```

This is an explicit way, but pandas has a quicker way. In your original snippet, you also used the argument `parse_data=True` in the `read_csv()`. You can print `df1.dtypes` to see if the column `created_on` was already successfully converted to datetime objects. If so, you'd only have to change the NaT/NaN values to None.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you suggestinos but firstly dates are not getting parsed and they are still in m/d/Y format
custom_date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\adminuser\Desktop\CSAExcel\CSA_Monthly_Incident_Resolved_COM_Report.csv', parse_dates=True,date_parser=custom_date_parser , usecols = [columns],encoding='cp1252')  
and secondly 
df1['created_on']= pd.to_datetime(df1['created_on'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df1['created_on'] = df1['created_on'].apply(lambda t: None if pd.isnull(t) else t) 
sets all the dates to null